# Problems when creating child theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

Im trying to create a child theme in wordpress but im getting this error

> Broken Themes
>
> The following themes are installed but incomplete.
>
> Name  Description
> Rife child  Template is missing. Standalone themes need to have a index.php template file. Child themes need to have a Template header in the style.css stylesheet.

What am i doing wrong?

**Here is the files**
Style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Rife child
Description: Made by <a href="http://apollo13themes.com/" target="_blank">Apollo13</a>.<br/> Get support from <a href="http://support.apollo13.eu/" target="_blank">Forum</a>.
Author: Apollo13
Author URI: https://apollo13themes.com/
Theme URI: https://apollo13themes.com/themes
License: GNU General Public License version 3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
Tags: theme-options, post-formats, two-columns, translation-ready
Text Domain: rife
Version: 1.0
*/
```

Functions.php

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .     '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

Comment: Follow this detail guide,

https://prabinparajuli.com.np/create-a-wordpress-child-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's only two files required in child theme: the **style.css** and the functions.php.

I simply think that your **style.css** is missing the header. Here's an example of the mandatory header of a child theme.

```
/*
 Theme Name: My Child Theme
 Theme URI: https://www.example.com/themes
 Description: My Child Theme
 Author: John Deo
 Author URI: https://www.example.com/
 Template: parent_theme_name
 Version: 1.0
 Text Domain: my-child-theme
*/
```

Also, you need to enqueue the parent style sheet by including this in your child theme **function.php**:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
?>
```

Comment: Im not familiar with PHP so im a little confused about this. Could you write the functions.php file so its correct or point out where i should change the code?

Comment: what's you theme name. you can check here `wp-content/themes/name_of_theme/`

Comment: My parent theme name is Rife.

Comment: It worked! i see that the crucial part was the "template" line, where it finds it parent theme, i didnt include this in my style.css. I thought however it was written like this "parent_theme_rife" but that didnt work out so tried just rife like Kamil said and then it worked. This was new to me as i didnt know wordpress picks up data from the comments, i thought this header was just for information for the developer to see.